# Php preg_split add an empty field on result

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I try to split a GPS coordinate with function:

```
$long = "13°47'52.544\"E";
$res = preg_split("/[°'\"]/", $long);
```

but result is:

```
array(0=>13, 1=>, 2=>47, 3=>52.544, 4=>E)
```

why item 1 is add to result ?

Example here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/nPv

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534863/splitting-a-string-containing-a-longitude-or-latitude-expression-in-perl, it uses  [^\dNSEW.]+

Comment: Interesting this appproach too. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`°` is two bytes `0xC2 0xB0` and you are not in Unicode "mode". Therefore, it is splitting on the `0xC2` and again on the `0xB0`, with an empty item in the middle.

Enable Unicode mode with the `u` modifier.

```
$long = "13°47'52.544\"E";
$res = preg_split("/[°'\"]/u", $long);
```